# store and retrieve serialized HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, serialization, store

How I can store one o more HTML structure like that in PHP and MYSQL DB,

```
<li class='ui-state-default ui-sortable full w4-4'>
<div class='element-handler'>
<a href='#edit-element' class='edit revs-edit-element'>Edit</a>
<a href='#del' class='del-element delete'>X</a>
</div>
<div class='element'>
<span class='element-name'>Element name</span>
</div>
<textarea rows='6' cols='10' class='text-shortcode'>
[revs_flexslider page='home'] [shortcode page='home']
[shortcode page='home'][revs_shortcode page='home']
</textarea>
</li>
```

and retrive it for append  in a

```
<ul id="contenitore" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
```

whit serialization

Comment: There are multiple ways to store the information, but in MySQl, you would typically use the [`insert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) command. And then to display, there are multple ways to do it as well, but typically an [`echo`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the entire structure in php variable.

```
$structure = "<li class='ui-state-default ui-sortable full w4-4'>
<div class='element-handler'>
<a href='#edit-element' class='edit revs-edit-element'>Edit</a>
<a href='#del' class='del-element delete'>X</a>
</div>
<div class='element'>
<span class='element-name'>Element name</span>
</div>
<textarea rows='6' cols='10' class='text-shortcode'>
[revs_flexslider page='home'] [shortcode page='home']
[shortcode page='home'][revs_shortcode page='home']
</textarea>
</li>";
```

then run the sql query

```
insert into table (structure) values ('$structure');
```

to retrieve it just use select statement.

```
select * from table_name;
```

and the output of select in the

```
<ul id="contenitore" class="connectedSortable"><?php echo $select_output ?></ul>
```